# Is this java leetcode solution use quadratic time in the worst case?

Tags: java, time-complexity

I was doing exercise in the leetcode website. I tried this solution for the Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters problem. The judging system accept the answer and return a good runtime. When I tried to analysis the time complexity, I found it took quadratic time when the input string is unique.The inside for loop will execute i-1 times every time, which means it will execute (n-1)+(n-2)+.....+1=(n-1)n/2 times. Am I right?

```
public class Solution {
    public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
        // Note: The Solution object is instantiated only once and is reused by each test case.
        if(s == null) return 0;
        char[] str = s.toCharArray();
        if(str.length == 0) return 0;
        int max = 1;
        int barrier = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < str.length; i++){
            for(int j = i - 1; j >= barrier;j--){
                if(str[i] == str[j]){
                    barrier = j + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            max = Math.max(max, i - barrier + 1);
        }
        return max;   
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the input string is unique" ?

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem completly quadratic to me, bacause `int j = i - 1`. So in the beginning j is significally shorter than i. But in the end J becomes I and you get a quadratic time, but not for the whole string. Just for the last part.

Comment: This is not very mathematically rigorous

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right it's quadratic. If every character is unique, then the condition will always be false, and barrier will remain 0. This gives you the worst-case scenario. If you ignore the constant-time statements, and replace barrier with 0, you end up with:

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

The number of iterations here is:

```
0 + 1 + 2 + ... + (n - 1) = ((n - 1) * n) / 2 = (n^2 - n) / 2 = O(n^2)
```